# Too many unprocessed floats with marginpar

Tags: floats, marginpar, errors

I'm updating my CV, which is written by modifying [this template](http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex). I have always been very happy with the result, but now I'm getting a *Too many unprocessed floats* error.

For those who do not want to have a look at the template, it basically works like this. In the preamble I have a command

```
\newcommand{years}[1]{\marginpar{\scriptsize #1}}
...
\begin{document}
\reversemarginpar
```

which one then uses like

```
\section*{Seminars}
\years[2005]Blah blah...
\\
\years[2007]Blah blah blah..
```

The problem is, when I insert the 10th item, I get the *Too many unprocessed floats* error.

Inserting a clearpage is not an option, since it would just leave half page empty. Also, doing a major change to the CV, like switching to another template or using a CV class is not an option either. I have tried many different ways to write my CV; it always takes time to switch, and I need to compile it soon. Moreover I'm very happy with this template.

**Is there a way to increase the number of floats that LaTeX can handle?**

Comment: Remark, in your "MWE" you missed a backslash before the command name, see this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29463/250119

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The package [`morefloats`](http://ctan.org/pkg/morefloats) doubles the number of floats that can be handled.

Comment: Wow, you saved my day!

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38609/4427) in case also the `etex` package is used.

Comment: "The package morefloats doubles the number of floats" *by default*. You can also say `\usepackage[maxfloats=25]{morefloats}` or `\usepackage[morefloats=7]{morefloats}` to get 18+7=25 floats. maxfloats between 18 and 266, at least for a recent version: 2011/07/10 v1.0e.

Comment: Make that 256 instead of 266 (my mistake, sorry).

Answer (score 2):

I did not know about the `morefloats` package, but I'll try using it to solve my problem.

To solve that problem there is another solution, but in theory not a very good one although it does work great:

Just use `[H]` instead of `[htbp]` as float specifier. What happens is that LaTeX stops freaking out with too many unprocessed floats.

Comment: "However, if your floats can’t be placed anywhere [e.g. because it is just too large for the page], extending the number of floats merely delays the arrival of the inevitable error message." (http://ctan.org/pkg/morefloats)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the definition of the `\years` command by something like the following:

```
\newcommand{\years}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip-.6in{\scriptsize #1}}}
```

If you need to introduce line breaks within the years, something slightly more complicated is needed. Then you might want to consider using `\parbox` and `\raisebox` in the definition of the `\years` command, but this shouldn't usually be necessary.

Since you are not using any floats anymore, LaTeX will stop complaining.