# How to make an appendix with only tables without "too many unprocessed floats" errors?

Tags: floats, appendices, positioning

I'm often writing reports containing over 50 tables and over 200 figures that have to be included in appendices. The problem is obvious: if you just make an appendix

```
\chapter{Tables}
\begin{table}
 ...
\end{table}

\begin{table}
 ...
\end{table}
...
```

at a certain point you get the "too many unprocessed floats" error. I've tried specifying `[h]`, `[h!]` and so many other variants, but somehow LaTeX doesn't want to agree on just placing them one after the other, and saves them up. My current solution is to add `\afterpage{\clearpage}` every so often, but this requires me to manually reposition them a number of times before the layout is more or less acceptable.

How should this be done without all the manual manipulations?

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1650/too-many-unprocessed-floats-with-marginpar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only have floats, then they don't need to float. Using the H placement offered by the float package is probably the easiest way.

Comment: This did the trick. The morefloats package @Yiannis mentioned seems promising as well, but for my problem the H placement is more than enough. thx

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the [morefloats](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/morefloats/morefloats.pdf) package. The literature also of the package has a number of good solutions for this type of problem.