# Error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: macros, errors

I wanted to make a command that outputs a number in math mode. This is how my file looks like:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{epsdice}
%\newcommand{dice}[1]{\epsdice{#1}}

\newcommand{dice}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{document}
```

But when I compile this with XeTeX, I always get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \newcommand{dice}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
```

I have not that much experience with TeX, I think the solution is quite easy.

Comment: I edited your title so other people with the same problem can find this question more easily, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @doncherry Nevermind. Having the right of constructive edits on people's questions and answers is IMHO one of the fundamental principles of the whole Stackexchange / -overflow family.

Comment: Note that you will end up with the same error message if your new command name includes numbers, even with the leading backslash (just happened to me). E.g. https://blate.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/missing-begindocument-error-with-newcommand-in-latex-preamble/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're just missing a backslash in the command definition, it should be

```
\newcommand{\dice}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
```

Comment: The point being that Latex emits the "Missing \begin{document}." if it has something that looks like it should be output, but it has not yet met the "\begin{document}" command.  Latex will run tokens after the first in its first argument: try passing `{d\ice}`, `{\d\ice}`, or `{\d i}`.

Comment: The helpful news is that LaTeX tells you the first line it objects to (line 1.13 in this example).