# Why doesn't latexmk handle errors in the preamble?

Tags: errors, compiling, latexmk, preamble

Today I discovered that if I have an error *in the preamble* of my tex file then `Latexmk` produce an error only once.

Precisely, for example if my file looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\someWrongCommand{foo}
\begin{document}
bar
\end{document}
```

then of course both `latexmk` and `pdflatex` produce an error in the line `\someWrongCommand{foo}`. But if I then compile the file with `latexmk` for the second time (without changing anything in my file) then `letexmk` just says

```
Latexmk: All targets (file.pdf) are up-to-date
```

Whats more, if I have an error in the document (*not in the preamble*) then `latexmk` shows an error all the time (not only in the first compile) as I wish.

Is it possible to make `latexmk` behaves like `pdflatex` if there is an error in a preamble? I know I can use `latexmk` with `-g` option but it is not a solution because then it always recompile everything from scratch.

I just want `latexmk` to handles errors in the preamble no matter in which compilation.

Comment: From limited testing (TeXworks 0.4.3 r858 on Windows), it looks like if you cancel `latexmk` on the error, it won't build a PDF, and will act like `pdflatex` as you want. If you hit `Enter` to get past the errors, a PDF will be built (in your case, with the words `foo` and `bar` in one paragraph). If that happens, there's no way for `latexmk` to know that it needs to rebuild the PDF until you make a change to the source file.

Comment: See also [the comment under this answer to the same error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29464/3345). You've got a different cause, somewhat, but an identical root cause: "The point being that Latex emits the 'Missing \begin{document}.' if it has something that looks like it should be output, but it has not yet met the '\begin{document}' command."

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Thanks for your comments. Indeed if `latexmk` didn't build output file (and there is no old one!) then it always show an error. But if I previously compile my tex file and there was no error (I have an output PDF file) and then produce an error (_in a preamble_) then `latexmk` print an error only once. I know it would be enough to make `latexmk` remove/doesn't save output if it get an error but it behaves like this only for error in document (_outside_ preamble).

Answer (score 5):

From `latexmk`'s point of view, errors in the preamble are treated no differently than those in the body.  If you are getting a difference, it is because you or `pdflatex` are reacting differently to the error.

The behavior of `latexmk` follows from that of `pdflatex` and is as follows:

- If `pdflatex` finds an error and you tell it to exit, then no pdf file is created.  Any already existing pdf file will be unchanged.
- If you respond to error by telling `pdflatex` to continue, then a new pdf file will (normally) be produced.  (But `latexmk` will see that there is an error, and not do postprocessing, e.g., forcing a previewer update.)

On a subsequent run, if the pdf file exists and if the source files are unchanged, then `latexmk` will not rerun `pdflatex`.  This is normally correct behavior, since (normally) rerunning `pdflatex` won't change the error condition until a source file is changed.  If there is no pdf file, a subsequent run of `latexmk` will notice the non-existence of the pdf file and therefore (pointlessly) rerun `pdflatex` and reproduce the error.  (Perhaps I need `latexmk` to cache the existence of an error condition, and save the extra run.)

I definitely don't want to change `latexmk` to remove the pdf file if `pdflatex` reports an error, since generally the principle of `latexmk` is that it should respect the behavior of the programs it calls.