# Special behavior if optional argument is not passed

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I am looking to define a command (actually, an environment, but that shouldn't matter for the purposes of this question) that does some default behavior, and if an optional argument is passed, does something else.

For example,

```
\newcommand{mycommand}[1]{%
if (#1 != NULL){%
The argument #1 was passed}
else {%
No argument was passed.}}
```

Obviously this is not valid LaTeX, but hopefully this makes it clear what I am trying to do.  Is there a way to do this with ordinary LaTeX?  Is it worth switching to LuaLaTeX to accomplish behavior like this?

Comment: Remark, in your "MWE" you missed a backslash before the command name, see this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29463/250119

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it easily with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{o}{%
  % <code>
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {code when no optional argument is passed}
    {code when the optional argument #1 is present}%
  % <code>
}

\begin{document}

\mycommand

\mycommand[HERE]

\end{document}
```

This will print

> code when no optional argument is passed
>   code when the optional argument HERE is present

For an environment it's similar

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{o}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#1}{start code no opt arg}{start code with #1}}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#1}{end code no opt arg}{end code with #1}}
```

Other code common to the two cases can be added at will. As you see, `xparse` also allows (but it's not mandatory) to use the argument specifiers also in the end part.

Answer (score 22):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][\@nil]{%
  \def\tmp{#1}%
   \ifx\tmp\@nnil
       no argument
    \else
         argument #1
    \fi}
\makeatother



\mycommand zzzz \mycommand[hello]  zzz
```

Comment: What is the command \@nnil ?

Comment: @sergiokapone: That was a minor typo on David's side :) The default optional argument should just match whatever you use against the test; `\relax` would have worked just as well.

Comment: @Werner no sorry it was not a typo, and `\relax` would not work as well, I reverted the edit. `\@nnil` is defined in the latex format by `\def\@nnil{\@nil}` for exactly this test

Comment: @sergiokapone `\@nnil` is `\def\@nnil{\@nil}` so it is equal to `\tmp` if the default argument of `\@nil` is used in the case the command has no explicit argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, I was too eager to add some mortar to your brick.

Comment: Please could you explain /why/ you use `\@nnil` instead of `\@nil`? I can't find this online.

Comment: With the `tufte-book` class, this gives me `\@nil undefined control sequence`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the LaTeX internal [`\@ifnextchar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/understanding-ifnextchar):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\def\foo{\@ifnextchar[\foo@BT\foo@BF}
\def\foo@BT[#1]{Bracket true. Optional argument was: #1.}
\def\foo@BF{Bracket false. No optional argument.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foo[Hello, world]

\foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not use `minimal` for examples as it is not suitable for this purpose.