# Nested newcommand and expanding \@nil

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'm creating a command to generate a series of macros all with equivalent styling. i.e. something along the lines of <sup>[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217763/54688)</sup>

```
\newcommand{\newcustommacro}[2]{\newcommand{#1}[1][Default]{#2{##1}}}
\newcustommacro{\macroA}{\textbf}
```

Now, I want my macro to have [Special behavior if optional argument is not passed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217763/54688) so I'm using David Carlisle's answer from that question.

However, when that `\newcommand` method is nested inside another `\newcommand` then it stops working.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testA}[1][\@nil]{
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\@nnil%
    No arg: Hello%
  \else
    Yes arg: Bye(#1)%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\makeamacro}[2]{%
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand{#1}[1][\@nil]{
    \def\tmp{##1}%
    \ifx\tmp\@nnil%
      No arg: Hello%
    \else
      Yes arg: #2(##1)
    \fi
  }
  \makeatother
}

\makeamacro{\testB}{Bye}

\begin{document}

  testA, no arg: \testA

  testA, yes arg: \testA[arg]

  testB, no arg: \testB

  testB, yes arg: \testB[arg]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I doubled the #'s as required for passing arguments to nested newcommands. What do I need to do for the @'s? I'm stumped.

I have no averstion to `xparse` so if someone suggests a nested verison of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217764/54688) to the same question linked above then that'd be ok too.

---

[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217763/54688): I know the example is just making a macro that is basically just `\textbf{}`

Comment: Wrong position of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're placing `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the wrong place.

Whey you want to use macros with `@` in their name, such as `\@nnil`, the *whole* code should be surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testA}[1][\@nil]{% <--- don't forget
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\@nnil
    No arg: Hello%
  \else
    Yes arg: Bye(#1)%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\makeamacro}[2]{%
  \newcommand{#1}[1][\@nil]{% <--- don't forget
    \def\tmp{##1}%
    \ifx\tmp\@nnil
      No arg: Hello%
    \else
      Yes arg: #2(##1)
    \fi
  }
}
\makeatother

\makeamacro{\testB}{Bye}

\begin{document}

  testA, no arg: \testA

  testA, yes arg: \testA[arg]

  testB, no arg: \testB

  testB, yes arg: \testB[arg]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This said, `xparse` is easier under this respect:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testA}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {No arg: Hello}%
    {Yes arg: Bye(#1)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeamacro}{mm}{%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{o}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{##1}
      {No arg: Hello}%
      {Yes arg: #2(##1)}%
  }%
}
```

Comment: That was easy to fix.

Comment: @tmgriffiths The concept of category codes is not so easy to grasp, but once one gets the hang of it, it becomes almost routine. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you search for something like that? (xparse)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testA}{o D(){Bye}}{
  \IfNoValueTF {#1}
    {No arg: Hello}
    {Yes arg: #2(#1)}
}

\begin{document}

  testA, no arg: \testA 

  testA, yes arg: \testA[arg]

  testA, yes arg: \testA[arg](notbye)

\end{document}
```